# R: How to count the number of circuits completed by a moving object?

Tags: r, geometry

I have data of a tracked object in (x,y) coordinates. The object moves irregularly around a container of constant dimensions, with a center (a,b) ≠ 0.
Suppose I have data like the generated by the following code:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = c(radius * cos(theta) + rnorm(20, 2, 0.2),
                       radius * cos(theta) + rnorm(20, 2, 0.4)),
                 y = c(radius * sin(theta) + rnorm(20, 2, 0.2),
                       radius * sin(theta) + rnorm(20, 2, 0.4)))
plot(c(0, 4), c(0, 4), type = "n")
# First circuit
lines(df$x[1:20], df$y[1:20], col = 2)
# A second circuit
lines(df$x[21:40], df$y[21:40], col = 3)
```

Plotted:

[image]

Question: Is there a way to count the number of laps (or 'circles') completed by this object? (In my example, there is just one full lap -the red).

I can't figure out how to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:

It's possible to solve this by summing the angles and divide by 360?

Comment: I have two conceptions of the topological definition of circuit and "1" is not the right answer for either of them. I would have said that topologically you have 0 circuits but that naively you have 2. I'm asking for a more precise definiion of circuit that does not depend on ones starting location and direction for a test cut.

Comment: @IRTFM sorry. What I want is just to count the number of (irregular) spins, considering that the ending location crossed or is the same as the starting location, relative to a horizontal line that passes through the starting location. Is this clearer?

Comment: Not to me. I don't see that either path is plotted in a way that makes it appear to have arrives at "the starting location". But maybe ... Your suggested test of completion is that the vertical coordinate has differences that are positive, negative, positive and ends up at a higher value than starting?

Comment: Thanks @IRTFM, do you have a sugestion to improve the Q? In the dataset, the starting location of the first lap is df$x[1], df$y[1]. Supposing I find the ending location, The next two (x, y) will be the second starting point. The number of spins will be the number of ending points. But I'm not sure this reasoning is right. If you have a suggestion please let me know.

Comment: It would have helped me (trivially) if you could have specified `radius` and `theta` and (more substantively) if you could have specified whether there were always a nominal "center". I suppose you could compute center nominees by taking the means of x and y of separate series. I was thinking you could compute the "angular progression" around a center and see if it reached 2*pi.